# Why is kernel_required.rb in my stack trace?

Tags: ruby, error-handling

I forgot to put the word end, at the end of a if statement,
and got the following error:

```
/home/***/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require': **/home/****/Desktop/ruby/food_finder/lib/restaurant.rb:84: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)**
    from /home/****/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from /home/****/Desktop/ruby/food_finder/lib/guide.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/****/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from /home/****/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from init.rb:14:in `<main>'
```

my code without errors:

```
def self.saved_restaurants
        # read the restaurant file
        restaurants = []
        if file_usable?
            file = File.new(@@filepath, 'r')

            file.each_line do |line|
                restaurants << Restaurant.new.import_line(line.chomp)
            end

            file.close
        **end** -- > forgotten end
        # return instances of restaurant
        return restaurants
    end
```

my code with errors:

```
def self.saved_restaurants
        # read the restaurant file
        restaurants = []
        if file_usable?
            file = File.new(@@filepath, 'r')

            file.each_line do |line|
                restaurants << Restaurant.new.import_line(line.chomp)
            end

            file.close
         -- > forgotten end
        # return instances of restaurant
        return restaurants
    end
```

My questions are:
Why do i get errors that has noting to do with my code?
like the following:

```
/home/***/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require':
```

1. What does this error mean?

When i use the correct syntax for the saved_restaurants method, i don't get any error.

Answer (score 3):

Your file `restaurant.rb` is read by a method call `require` in `guide.rb`, which is defined in [`kernel_require.rb`](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/master/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb). Within its method definition, it has this part:

```
def require path

  ...

rescue LoadError => load_error

  ...

  raise load_error
end
```

When you have a syntax error in the file that is read, that will raise a `LoadError`, which is rescued, and will be raised as an error of `require`.

Comment: Now, the real question is: why is it designed to do so? I do not have an answer to that.

Comment: Why is it designed to do? anyone?

Comment: I just asked a question about it.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly there is a file named guide.rb which does:

```
require restaurant
```

Basically, require is a function implemented in kernel_require.rb whose prototype is like:

```
require path
```

Here path is restaurant.rb and this function fails because the require function is unable to load the rb file because of syntax error.

Remember you are looking at the call stack so the function with missing end should not show up because that function is not called but only the ruby file is loaded.