# Why is a syntactic error in a subfile designed to be rescued by `require`?

Tags: ruby, syntax-error, require

As asked by liron in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16624259), a syntax error in a `require`-d subfile is rescued by the method `require` and is raised as an error of `require`. Why is it designed like this? What is the benefit of attributing the error to `require` and not the syntax error in the subfile that is read? My understanding is that this feature was introduced when the gem system became standard part of Ruby. It could be related to that.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant portion of the stack trace in question:

```
/home/***/.rvm/.../rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require':
 .../food_finder/lib/restaurant.rb:84: 
syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)**
```

It *does* say where the error is.

The syntax error is wrapped in an error from  `require` because that's where the error is raised: the file is being processed by the `require` *method*. If there's an error in the *required* file, it's wrapped by the error handling in `require`.

It's rescued by `require` (and potentially re-raised) so the original `require` method can be tried under a variety of circumstances relating to not finding the file and gem failures.

Are you suggesting that `require`, which is just another method, be somehow special-cased so error handling operates in a completely different way? And that the ROI of doing so is worth it?

The "benefit" to not subverting how Ruby works is that it remains uniform. I see little ROI in doing so when the error is explicitly stated. Some of the confusion may come from not grokking that `require` is just another method–but it is, and as such, follows the same rules as the rest of the language.

Comment: Your first paragraph may be an answer to the linked question, but not to my question. You are just repeating the question. And the location of the error can be returned directly as a syntax error. It does not need to be wrapped. Regarding your second paragraph, I am not suggesting anything; I am asking.

Comment: @sawa It's "designed" that way because that's how the language works: stack traces originate from there the error is raised, and it's raised in `require`. In order to *not* work like that you'd need to subvert how Ruby works, or special-case a specific set of methods. "The benfit" is keeping the language uniform and predictable. The first paragraph is what's called "exposition", in this case, setting up required knowledge. Without it, the answer would be incomplete.

Comment: You are wrong. It is designed to work that way because the package overwrote `require` that way, not because the core Ruby language works that way. By rescuing the raised error, the error location is altered. Are you saying that the stack trace will be the same with and without the `rescue`? Then, why is it there?

Comment: @sawa I'm saying that rubygems has its own require because it operates differently, e.g., can load-on-demand. In order to not use the normal exception handling mechanisms you would need to subvert how Ruby works, and that the ROI to do so (if it's even *possible*) would not be worth it. I fail to see how anything about that is wrong-please elucidate your reasoning.